# Horizontal scrolling ListView.builder inside SingleChildScrollView - wrap content height

Tags: flutter, listview, layout, horizontal-scrolling

My layout is a Form widget with some controls:

```
Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Form(
          key: widget.addEventFormKey,
          onChanged: () {},
          child: Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  Text(CustomResources.strings["add_event_category_label"], style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  
                  /*some other widgets*/
                  
                  Visibility(
                    child: Container(
                      height: 200.0,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        itemCount: _attachments?.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Stack(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 5, 0),
                                child: Stack(
                                  children: [
                                    ClipRRect(
                                      child: Image.file(File(_attachments[index]), cacheWidth: 200),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              IconButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  File(_attachments[index]).delete();
                                  setState(() => _attachments.remove(_attachments[index]));
                                },
                                icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.trash, color: Colors.white, size: 20),
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4, left: 4),
                                constraints: BoxConstraints(),
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    visible: _attachments.length > 0,
                  ),
                  Visibility(child: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 18, 0, 0)),visible: _attachments.length > 0),
                  SizedBox(
                    child: RaisedButton(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0)),
                        onPressed: _attachments.length < 3 ? () => _pickImage() : null,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        child: Text(CustomResources.strings["add_event_add_photo_button_label"], style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
                    width: double.infinity,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Problematic part is `ListView.builder` to display horizontally scrolled list of images. As you can see, picture will always get fixed width (200) and unknown height, because height depends from image aspect ratio. `ListView.builder` is wrapped with `Container`, so now it has constant height 200.

I want to force my `ListView.builder` to expand to child image height (it's single row ListView scrolled horizontally), image width always 200 and other widgets should be placed below it without any remaining space. With current approach, if image height is < 200, there will be remaining space left below image list. If image height is >200, image will be scaled (width/height).

I tried to wrap list view with `Expanded` widget instead `Container`, but it throws exception:

> RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints
> are unbounded.

It says I still need to provide height, which I don't want to. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think that's not possible with `ListView.builder`, because its height with dynamic items is not known while building widgets tree. Instead, my thumbnail widgets mus be built upfront, and added to `Row` after they have been built and wrap row with `SingleChildScrollView` to make it scrollable. So, my thumbnails list ready to place to my `Form`:

```
class AttachmentsListWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const AttachmentsListWidget({
    Key key,
    @required this.items,
    @required this.onAttachmentDeleted,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final List<String> items;
  final Function(String) onAttachmentDeleted;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var _thumbnailsScrollController = ScrollController();
    final thumbnails = <Widget>[];
    Widget thumbnailsWidget;

    if (items.length > 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        thumbnails.add(
          AttachmentWidget(
            attachment: items[i],
            onDeleteClicked: (String attachment) => onAttachmentDeleted(attachment),
          ),
        );
      }
      thumbnailsWidget = Container(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Scrollbar(
              isAlwaysShown: true,
              controller: _thumbnailsScrollController,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                controller: _thumbnailsScrollController,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                child: Row(
                  children: thumbnails,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    } else {
      thumbnailsWidget = Container();
    }
    return thumbnailsWidget;
  }
}
```

(also, always visible scrollbar added).

Answer (score 0):

If you got `RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.` try below code hope its help to you. add your Column inside **Expanded()** Widget and remove **SingleChildScrollView()** in your code

```
Expanded(
  child: Column(
     children:[
     //Your Widgets
      ],
   ),
),
```

Comment: Do you mean to remove top level SingleChildScrollView? I can't remove it, because window content needs to be scrollable

Comment: yes , But I think When we use Expanded widget the content also scrollable just try it and let me know.

Comment: No, it's not scrollable. And I think top level widget is not related to issue. Problem is thumbnail list height